# Most efficient way to iterate over list of objects

Tags: python

This is a list of object:

```py
obj_list = [obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4, ... ,objn]
```

Object look like this:

```py
def __init__(self, number):
  self.number = number
```

What is the most efficient way to compare obj.number to all the objects in a list?

What I`ve tried:

```py
for i in range(0, len(obj_list)):
  temp = obj_list[i]
  count = i + 1

  for j in range(count, len(obj_list)):
    temp1 = obj_list[j]
    
    if temp.number == temp1.number:
      print("same")
```

But it's slow when a list is big. Thanks for any tips.

Comment: Sort the list based on the number attribute. Then check for contiguous runs of objects with the same number.

Comment: @Erri000 : Do you have 2 list or one list

Comment: What is your goal? You are trying to find any objects that have the same number?

Comment: @codeholic24 one list

Comment: @Erri000 : Can you tell me the purpose of this. Share the output you are expecting. Are you expecting to output the repeated values in list. Is that your goal ?

Answer (score 0):

If youre comparing class items, I'd recommend writing your own dunder methods for the less-than (<, **lt**) and greater-than, etc. methods. Here is an example of how you can use the python builtin `sorted()` method on a list of custom `Number` classes:

```py
class Number():
    def __init__(self, number) -> None:
        self.number = number

    def __gt__(self, other) -> bool:
        return self.number > other.number

    def __lt__(self, other) -> bool:
        return self.number < other.number

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.number}"

obj_list = [Number(7), Number(3), Number(2), Number(9)]
print(sorted(obj_list))
# >>> [2, 3, 7, 9]
```

There's a lot of good documentation on the python Dunder/Magic methods out there if you need further reading on this.

Answer (score 0):

The shortest answer would be:

```
for obj_i in obj_list:
    for obj_j in obj_list:
        if obj_i.number == obj_j.number
            print("same")
```

You are incrementing `count` and using in `for j in range(count, len(obj_list)):` but this makes objects before the current object not being compared.